# Looking for a condition on a subspace of a Hausdorff topological space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space and $C$ be a closed subspace of
$X$ with induced topology. I am looking for some topological
conditions on the space $C$ such that if $U_1$ and $U_2$ are two
open (or closed) subsets of $X$ with $C\cap U_1=C\cap U_2$, then
$U_1=U_2$. I tried to show that if $C$ is a dense subspace of $X$
then the above result is true, but I could not to do. My
professor said that there are at least three such properties.

Comment: $C$ must be dense, because if $C\cap U = \emptyset = C\cap \emptyset$, then $U = \emptyset$. Hence, $C\cap U \neq \emptyset$ for every open $U$ such that $U\neq \emptyset$. Conversely, as you say, the density of $C$ is also a sufficient condition.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I am looking for other properties as my professor said.

Comment: A closed and dense subset of $X$ equals $X$, so then the statement is trivially true.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $C$ is a closed set of $X$ with the property that for all open sets $U_1 , U_2$ of $X$ we have $$U_1 \cap C = U_2 \cap C \rightarrow U_1 = U_2$$ then $C = X$.

Suppose $C \neq X$, then define $U_1 = X\setminus C \neq \emptyset$ which is open as $C$ is closed. Also define $U_2 = \emptyset$. Then $U_1 \cap C= \emptyset = U_2 \cap C$.
But $U_1 \neq U_2$, contradiction. So $C= X$.

As formulated now, there aren't three topological conditions on $C$ that will ensure the property. Just being $X$.

Answer (score 0):

The proof goes without saying if $C$ is dense in $(X,\tau)$, for by definition $\overline{C}=X$ and since $C$ is closed $C=\overline{C}$ or rather $C=X$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am looking for other properties as my professor said.